# Assign value in main to a class static variable

Tags: c++, ros

I got the next code:

```
class Pipeline{
public:
  static Pipeline foo;
  bool hello(){
  ----
  }
}

bool bar(){
  Pipeline::foo::hello();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  // Some important process that must be running before creating Pipeline()
  Pipeline Pipeline::foo = Pipeline();
  bar();
}
```

I am trying to define an object as a static value. However, I found out that the static variable cannot be defined inside the main method so I have to do it outside, as in the example above.

How can I restructure the code to create the Pipeline object in the main(not to be created by defining the static variable outside of the main)?

Comment: You can assign the static in main. You can't define it there.

Comment: I just thought about that. I think we need more details about what the purpose of this is.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do it. static variable initialization is before any function. You can use a pointer or unique_ptr as you static variable. Then change/init it in the main function though.